# java how to create folder into shared drive using service account for authentication

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have a problem,**id folder not found**,I want to create file into **shared drive** inside folder that I have prepared before,this my code

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    Drive service = CreateFolder.createService();
    try {
        String key = "1kM_fdJek3b4sErr_xxx";
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("invoice");
        fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(key));
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");


        File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata)
                .setFields("id , parents").execute();


        System.out.println("folder successfully created by id " + file.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Drive createService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = new  GoogleCredential.Builder()
              .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
              .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
              .setServiceAccountId("my-email-id")
              .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File("privateKey.p12"))
              .build();


    return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}
```

this is **1kM_fdJek3b4sErr_xxx** key of folder,I am using service account to authorization and this is my private key file **privateKey.p12**.
my email id have been granted access to shared drive (my-email-id is content manager).but I get a problem that folder id is not found like message below

```
{  
"code" : 404,
    "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "fileId",
        "locationType" : "parameter",
        "message" : "File not found: 1kM_fdJek3b4sErr_xxx.",
        "reason" : "notFound"
      } ],
      "message" : "File not found: 1kM_fdJek3b4sErr_xxx."
}
```

I need help to create a file in the folder contained in shared drive

Answer (score 0):

> my email id have been granted access to shared drive (my-email-id is content manager).but I get a problem that folder id is not found like message below

A service account is NOT you.  A service account is its own dummy user it has its own drive account.  Granting yourself access to the shared drive is not going to give the service account access to it.  Share the folder with the service account by taking the service account email address and granting it permissions on the folder. It will then be able to see the folder.

Comment: email service account has been given permission,if I see details for that folder, there is also an email service account

Answer (score 0):

I get information from this link
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives

add this code

```
.setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
```

this full code

```
File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata)
                .setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
                .setFields("id , parents").execute();
```